# Can we increase the magnetic flux for a permanent magnet?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

When we pass current to the permanent magnet does its magnetic flux, magnetic property of attraction and repulsion increases? if possible
Is there any other way for increasing the magnetic flux?

Comment: magnetic fields can fluxuate when introduced to an electric current running perpindicular to its poles

Answer (score 1):

Take a solid magnet cylinder and put a coil inside of it made of a magnetic/conductive material. Here is how changing the flux induces current. You can use current to reverse this illustration.[image]

Comment: I think what he's asking is if we subject the _magnet itself_ to an electric current, how does that affect the magnetic field produced by it?

Comment: By taking a long bar shaped magnet coiling it then applying a current with or against the poles.

Comment: I came up with the same answer.  I like your answer better.

Comment: What if the coil is made up of magnetic material. Super electromagnets very thin and wide coils. Coil in coils.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot increase the *local* magnetic flux as it is conserved because of Maxwell's equations : $\vec{\nabla}.\vec{B} = 0$. However, you can use soft magnetic materials, often called [magnetic cores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_core) to concentrate the flux in a certain area and locally increase the magnetic field.

See [this](http://images.google.fr/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fhyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu%2Fhbase%2Fmagnetic%2Fimgmag%2Ficore.gif&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fhyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu%2Fhbase%2Fmagnetic%2Felemag.html&h=457&w=601&tbnid=Xgkf2OeIE8a0nM%3A&docid=825bv5n7yOX4zM&ei=CY3MVpq2M8XlUouZvOgH&tbm=isch&iact=rc&uact=3&dur=316&page=1&start=0&ndsp=36&ved=0ahUKEwja3s2Yq47LAhXFshQKHYsMD30QrQMIUDAR) picture that shows the effect of a magnetic core inserted inside of a solenoid : it tightens the field lines to create a greater magnetic field.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. When you can wrap a copper coil around a permanent magnet and adding current in the same and opposite direction of the positive pole to increase or even reverse the permanent magnets' field. Other wise building an electromagnet on top of the permanent magnet. You can deguass, move the poles and reinforce the direction of the magnetic fields. Just use a magnetic base instead of iron in a simple electromagnet.

References: Me